# Actualizar tabla mediante Trigger cuyo subquery depende de dos tablas

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo una tabla  A  que debe actualizarse automaticamente cuando existe una insercion en la tabla B. Mi problema es que que el valor y el criterio que necesito para actualizar la tabla A viene de una operación realizada sobre una columna de la tabla C. Por ello tengo que usar un "join" statement que no estoy empleando correctamente. Mis tablas se ven asi:

```
Tabla sale_order

| id_sale   | id_shopping_cart | 
|:--------- |:-----------------| 
| 1         | 2                |
```

```
Tabla shopping_cart

| id_shopping_cart| store_id | total   |
|:----------------|:------:  | -------:|
| 2               | 1        | 55      |
```

```
Tabla statistics 

| id_sale_statistic | store_id | total_sale_store |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 1                 | 1        | null             |
```

Busco que cuando se inserte un nuevo registro en sale_order, la tabla sales_statistics se actualice con la suma del total de la tabla shopping_cart, donde la store_id sea igual al nuevo registro en sales_order. Ahora, sales_order no contiene store_id pero si id_shopping_cart por lo que uso un join para traer store_id a este query.

Muestro mi trigger a continuacion:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_total_sales_store` AFTER INSERT ON `sale_order` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update sales_statistics  set total_sales_store=
(select  sum(total)  from  shopping_cart
 join sale_order where id_shopping_cart=new.id_shopping_cart)
 where store_id=shopping_cart.store_id;
END
```

```
Tabla statistics 

| id_sale_statistic | store_id | total_sale_store |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 1                 | 1        | null             |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 2                 | 2        | null             |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 3                 | 3        | null             |
|:------------------|----------|------------------|
```

La tabla statistics siempre tendrá 3 filas ya que solo existen 3 tiendas. Su usase un insert, se crearía una cuarta fila. Sin embargo, yo lo que busco es actualizar la columna total_sale_store, en la fila que corresponda al store_id que viene de la tabla shopping_cart.
Esto es un ejemplo de lo que busco:

```
insert into shopping_cart(id_shopping_cart, store_id,total) values(3,2,44);

| id_shopping_cart| store_id | total   |
|:----------------|:------:  | -------:|
| 3               | 2        | 44      |
| 4               | 1        | 33      |
| 5               | 2        | 6       |
```

```
insert into sale_order(id_sale,id_shopping_cart) values(2,3);

| id_sale   | id_shopping_cart | 
|:--------- |:-----------------| 
| 2         | 3                |
```

A continuación tiene efecto el trigger. La tabla statistics se actualiza en la columna total_sale_store en la segunda fila ya que la store_id que viene de shopping_cart es 2

```
| id_sale_statistic | store_id | total_sale_store |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 1                 | 1        | null             |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 2                 | 2        |     50           |
|:------------------|:------:  | -------:---------|
| 3                 | 3        | null             |
|:------------------|----------|------------------|
```

En la tabla shopping_cart se sumó la columna total en aquellas filas en las que el store_id es igual a dos. Dando como resultado que la tabla statistics se actualiza en su columna total_sale_store en su segunda fila con el valor 50.

Comment: Hola. Con que nos muestres las tablas como ya haces y nos digas qué columnas se relacionan con quien bastaría. Te pierdes en explicaciones sin dar en el punto: ¿Qué columna relaciona a `sale_order` con `statistics`? ¿La columna `id_shopping_cart` presente tanto en `sale_order` como en `shopping_cart` no sirve para la relación?

Comment: Gracias por tomar en cuenta mi pregunta. Hice una edición que podría dejar mas claro como se relaciolan mis tablas y lo que busco conseguir,.

Comment: Tal y como tienes diseñadas las tablas es imposible hacer lo que pretendes, aparte de que es un modelo algo extraño. Si he entendido bien tú querrías recoger todas las filas en `shopping_cart` que tengan el mismo `store_id` PERO desde una inserción en `sale_order`. El problema es que, en el momento de la inserción el dato de que dispones es este: `id_shopping_cart` y ese valor realmente no agrupa los valores en la tabla `shopping_cart`, es decir, tienes en esa tabla diferentes `id_shopping_cart` con el mismo `store_id` por tanto en la consulta que sumaría los valores ...

Comment: ... para hacer el `UPDATE` no tienes forma de agruparlos. Creo que deberías repensar el diseño de tus tablas. Por ejemplo: ¿cuál es la función de tu tabla `shopping_cart` y por qué no vas sumando los totales en esa misma tabla, donde sí tienes tanto el `store_id` como el `total`? Puedes disparar el TRIGGER desde esa tabla, actualizando el valor de `total`. O, puede que estemos hablando de un contexto mucho más amplio (hay otras tablas que intervienen en tu modelo y no nos los has contado). Lo cierto es que, como lo tienes ahora, es imposible hacer lo que pretendes.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece entender que lo que estás buscando es algo así, partiendo de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE sale_order(
  id_sale int,
  id_shopping_cart  int
  );
CREATE TABLE shopping_cart(
  id_shopping_cart int,
  store_id  int,
  total float
  );
CREATE TABLE statistics(
  id_sale_statistic int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id int,
  total_sale_store float
  );
INSERT INTO shopping_cart (id_shopping_cart, store_id, total) VALUES
  (2,1,55);
```

Y este disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_sales_store
AFTER INSERT ON sale_order
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO statistics
  SELECT NULL,store_id,SUM(total) total_sale_store 
    FROM shopping_cart
    WHERE store_id=(
      SELECT store_id FROM shopping_cart
        WHERE id_shopping_cart=new.id_shopping_cart
    );
END;
```

Al insertar:

```
INSERT INTO sale_order VALUES (NULL,2);
```

Obtendrás este resultado en tus tablas:

```
+---------+------------------+
| id_sale | id_shopping_cart |
+---------+------------------+
|       1 |                2 |
+---------+------------------+

+------------------+----------+-------+
| id_shopping_cart | store_id | total |
+------------------+----------+-------+
|                2 |        1 |    55 |
+------------------+----------+-------+

+-------------------+----------+------------------+
| id_sale_statistic | store_id | total_sale_store |
+-------------------+----------+------------------+
|                 1 |        1 |               55 |
+-------------------+----------+------------------+
```

Entiendo que necesitas un `INSERT` y no un `UPDATE` porque supongo que preferirás un histórico. Si quieres saber lo más reciente con esta consulta lo obtendrías:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics
  JOIN (
    SELECT store_id,
      MAX(id_sale_statistic) id_sale_statistic
      FROM statistics
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(store_id,id_sale_statistic);
```

Si lo único que buscas es una estadística del instante actual, sin histórico, con una simple consulta puedes obtenerla en cualquier momento y te evitas el trigger:

```
SELECT store_id,SUM(total) total_sale_store 
  FROM shopping_cart
  JOIN sale_order USING(id_shopping_cart)
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Si no es lo que buscabas, mete en tus tablas algún dato más de ejemplo e indica lo que te gustaría que apareciera en `statistics` para esos datos de muestra.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Hice una edición para dejar mas claro lo que busco. Debido a que se trata de una tarea, es necesario usar un trigger que actualice la tabla statistics de manera automatica.